# Swift 5.5+ Concurrency: how to pause multiple duplicate network fetches to wait for the first one?

Tags: swift-concurrency

I have code similar to the following. It uses the newer Swift Concurrency features available since Swift 5.5.

```
private actor Cache {
    static let shared = Cache()
    private var grape:Grape?
    func read() -> Grape? { return grape }
    func set(_ new: Grape) { grape = new }
}

private actor GrapeWorker {
    func fetch() async throws -> Grape {
        let url = URL(string: "https://grape.example.com/fetch")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        if let oldGrape = await Cache.shared.read() {
            return oldGrape
        } else {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            let freshGrape = try JSONDecoder().decode(Grape.self, from: data)
            await Cache.shared.set(freshGrape)
            return freshGrape
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class GrapeFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var grape: Grape?
    @Published private(set) var errMsg: String?
    private let worker = GrapeWorker()
    func fetch() async {
        do {
            grape = try await worker.fetch()
        } catch {
            errMsg = String(describing: error)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am trying to solve is that if `GrapeFetcher().fetch` is called multiple times, each a few milliseconds apart, then the network request will be duplicated.

How do I code it so that multiple calls are paused until the first call finishes. I would be happy with either sharing the first response with the other calls or having them wait and when they continue the `Cache.shared.read()` return a value.

I am trying to use the latest Swift 5.5+ concurrent features: `async/await`, `Task`, and so on as described here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/concurrency

To show what I have already tried is too lengthy, but I will summarize my attempts and what went wrong:

- infinite `while` do-nothing loop reading a shared `isLoading` property

  - hung threads even tho property changed
- The `SerialTask` snippet from [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72500580/how-to-suspend-subsequent-tasks-until-first-finishes-then-share-its-response-wit).

  - could not figure out in a few hours how to share response from 1 task with another
  - how to managed threaded access to `previousTask` shared property?
- AsyncSequence

  - custom iterator still needed access to shared property
- Combine.Subject

  - just reading the docs made me give up and try the next thing
- OSAllocatedUnfairLock

  - Apple and other sample code is too simple for me to extrapolate how to actually use it
  - the lock want sync code in its closure, but its exactly async stuff I want protected

Comment: See code snippet associated with WWDC 2021 video, [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/?time=720) at 11:59 as discussed in possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70586562/how-to-prevent-actor-reentrancy-resulting-in-duplicative-requests.